# What causes Skrill error LOCK_LEVEL_9 when sending money?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing, skrill

I am trying to send money (payout) from my business account to another Skrill account using API [as documented](https://www.skrill.com/fileadmin/templates/main/res/material/documents/pdf/getting-started/skrill-automated-payment-interface-manual-en-us.pdf), using a request like the following:

```
https://www.moneybookers.com/app/pay.pl?action=prepare&email=mymailid@host.com&password=6b4c1ba48880bcd3341dbaeb68b2647f&amount=500&currency=INR&bnf_email=beneficiary@domain.com&subject=some_subject&note=some_note&frn_trn_id=111
```

But I am getting the following error as the response:

```
<response>
<error>
<error_msg>LOCK_LEVEL_9</error_msg>
</error>
</response>
```

And my account is getting locked. I am trying these transactions using my two test accounts, one for merchant account and other for buyer account.

(I tried to send money from my Skrill account manually and it is working. But I need to implement this in my website, so I'm attempting to make the API work as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Add your IP in the developer settings section of your Skrill account under:

**"Allow payments only from the following IP addresses (separated by spaces)"**

That fixed this problem for me.
I assumed that 'no IP entered' meant any IP should work.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but in my testing and development with Skrill, this seems to be an automatic security lock on the 'merchant' account.  I believe it can be removed simply by performing a password reset for the merchant account.